# How to add to a list? Scala

Tags: scala

I'm completely new to scala and don't understand why this list isn't coming out right. When I run the program I just get List() as output when I should be getting a list of all the elements of the parameter squared. This should be very simple but the :+ operation is what I've found online and it isn't working.

```
def Squareall (l: List[Int]): List[Int] ={
  var r : List[Int]=List()
  for (i<-0 to l.length-1){
    r:+ l(i)*l(i)
  }
  return r
}
```

Comment: `:+` return a new list instead of appending to current list. You need to reassign your `r` everytime you create a new list by appending to current `r`. So... `r = r :+ l( i ) * l( i )`

Comment: Personally, I don't think using these operators ever gets easy. Except that I know what `x :: Nil` does. The docs were considered confusing enough that a PR was recently proposed, but rejected because the difficulties are too great. https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the newly created list to `r` like this:

```
r = r:+ l(i)*l(i)
```

This is because by default `List` in Scala is immutable and `:+` returns a new list, doesn't update the old one.

Of course there's also a mutable variation of a list `scala.collection.mutable.MutableList`. You can use the `.++=` method on it to grow the collection.

```
val mutableList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList(1, 2)
mutableList.++=(List(3, 4))
```

Answer (score 7):

The imperative coding style you have in your example is usually avoided in Scala. The `for` in Scala is an expression, meaning it results in a value, and thus you can transform your input list directly. To use a `for` to transform your input `List` you could do something like this:

```
def squareAll (l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  for (i <- l) yield i * i
}
```

If you don't supply the `yield` statement a `for` results in the `Unit` type, which is like `void` in Java. This flavor of `for` loop is generally for producing [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), like printing to the screen or writing to a file. If you really just want to transform the data, then there is no need to create and manipulate the resulting `List`. (Also method names in Scala are generally "camel cased".)

Most people would probably use the `List.map` method instead, though:

```
def squareAll (l: List[Int]) = l.map((x: Int) => x * x)
```

or even...

```
def squareAll (l: List[Int]) = l.map(Math.pow(_, 2.0))
```